# Phalcon model saves everything except new added attributes

Tags: php, phalcon-orm

I received an update of a Phalcon model class and I had to update my local data table with the new attributes the model contains. Usually this kind of operation is not a problem, I simply launch an alter SQL query on the to add the columns, assign values to the object, call save and that's it.

However this time something strange happened: when I call save() on the model, everything is updated/created except the two new attributes I've added in my table. I checked the logs to take a look at the raw SQL query and the two new attributes are missing, the funny thing is that this operation worked the first times I tested it.

I think this error might come from the framework, after debugging my code I see clearly that the model takes the new values but for some reason cannot pass it to the SQL query.

Thus my question is the following: is there a way to force the Phalcon model to be sync again with my table?

Comment: You may want to show us some code. Specially your model class and the code where you call `save()` and "is not working"

Comment: It won't help but I'll do it

Comment: @onizukaek Your question is from 4 years ago but now I have this problem :-D How did you fix it?!